# How to use pattern matching to assign values to Subscript[f,x_]?

Tags: pattern-matching, variable-definitions, upvalues

I want to define two subscripted functions `Subscript[f,1]` and `Subscript[f,2]`. To keep the assignments local, I would like to associate the definitions with `f` if possible. My current solution is to write the following.

```
f/:Subscript[f,1]:=Function[x,g[x]]
f/:Subscript[f,2]:=Function[x,h[x]]
```

The resulting definition is stored as an UpValue for `f`, which is acceptable for me. Is it possible to construct a similar definition using pattern matching? I am looking for an analog to the following pair of definitions.

```
f[x_]:=g[x] (*definition 1*)
f:=Function[x,g[x]] (*definition 2*)
```

In other words, I am currently using a definition akin to definition 2 above for my subscripted functions. Is it possible to write a definition analogous to definition 1 above?

Comment: Do you mean `f /: Subscript[f[x_], 1] := g[x]` ? Seems quite straight forward, so if that's your question you almost answered it yourself.

Comment: @jVincent, he doesn't mean that. He wants it for `Subscript[f,1][x_]` which would be too deep for an `UpValue`

Comment: I don't know a neat solution to these things, but workarounds are possible. Check out if symbolising the subscript is good for you

Comment: Rojo is correct; thank you for clarifying my intentions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the [Notation Package](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) and its [`Symbolize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/ref/Symbolize.html) function:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The definition is not attached to `Subscript`, but to pseudo-Symbol `f1`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 I still think symbolising is the best workaround, if you don't need the underscript to be a pattern

Comment: @Rojo I voted for yours too.  (And jVincent's, if anyone's curious.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard 500 th answer ! Seems like you've got enough ideas to write a new (and necessarily concise) `Mathematica` book. +1

Comment: @Artes Thanks! I hadn't noticed.   I'm no writer; I still haven't made a blog post yet.

Comment: This is probably the best answer for the situations that I can foresee. I admit that the workarounds using wrappers are quite enlightening (hence a +1 for each), but the situations that I would use this subscript notation are mostly in the context of small examples where it seems Symbolize offers the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 10):

As Rojo notes, defining `f/: Subscript[f,1][x_]` doesn't work as `f` is too deep in the expression, however you could define your function in two steps to avoid tying the definition to `Subscript`.

```
f /: Subscript[f, n_] := subs[f, n]
subs /: subs[f, n_][x_] := g[x]
```

This has the problem that `Subscript[f,1]` for instance will turn up in output as `subs[f,1]` rather then be nicely formated. You can however simply define that it should be formated like subscript and noone will be the wiser that it's actually a different wrapper:

```
MakeBoxes[subs[a_, n_], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes[Subscript[a, n], StandardForm]
```

Comment: Nice patch +1. Of course the actual value of the output is subs, and it could eventually bite you. I wonder if its possible to work around that too, humm

Comment: @Rojo I'm not sure how it would come back to bite me since Subscript is mostly just a formatting function, If you had code that acted different depending on the heads you could just define: `subs /: Head[subs[__]] = Subscript` in which case I think subs becomes a pretty good impostor Subscript.

Comment: The patch you just suggested will only work for code that explicitly uses `Head`, which will be the minority. I mean, a reason I see for the OP to want the "pattern version" of the definition is because in a real application his definition many times won't match. This will leave you with some symbolic expression with `subs` inside that you see and think as `Subscript` and it will bite you if you ever use `Cases` or `Replace` trying to get those expressions

Comment: An ideal solution would remain unevaluated when it doesn't match

Answer (score 6):

Slightly modifying @jVincent's idea so that if there's no match with your definition you go back to the `Subscript`

```
Module[{$guard = True, subs},
     f /: Subscript[f, n_] /; $guard = subs[f, n];
 subs[f, n_][sth_Integer] := g[sth];
 subs[f, n_][sth_] := Block[{$guard = False}, Subscript[f, n][sth]]
 ]
```

Now

```
Subscript[f, 1][2]    
Subscript[f, 1][2.5] // FullForm
```

> g[2]
>
> Subscript[f,1][2.5`]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach to creating a functionality similar to what Rojo does.

I attach a single rule to `Subscript`:

```
Subscript[x_, n_][args__] /; MatchQ[x, $subpat] :=
 With[{eval = x[n][args]},
  eval /; ! MatchQ[ eval, HoldPattern @ x[n][args] ]
 ]
```

Then I define functions that are controlled by this rule:

```
$subpat = HoldPattern[f | q];

f[1][x_] := x^2
f[2][x_] := Mod[x, 3]

q[1][x_] := x + 7
```

We gain this behavior:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`$subpat` controls the domain:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change `$subpat` or the definitions for `f`, `q`, etc. to "keep the assignments local" however you see fit.